# Must match document with keyword if it occurs, must match other document if keyword doesn't occur

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a query to return a document that "must match a document with keyword if keyword occurs in search phrase, or otherwise find another document that doesn't contain a keyword if that keyword doesn't occur in search phrase".

You can imagine an index with a store products that can be "regular" or "have something unusual" and when it's regular you don't add this to search phrase.

Like if we have this products:

- "Nike T-Shirt" (attributes: [])
- "Adidas T-Shirt" (attributes: ["collectible"])

If user searches for "t-shirt" we don't want him to find *any* collectible items. But when user searches for "collectible t-shirt" we want him to find *only* collectible items. There can be multiple of this kind of keywords.

---

Example:

##### I have some documents:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "First document",
    "variants": ["red", "big"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Second document",
    "variants": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Third entry",
    "variants": ["green", "big"]
  }
]
```

##### And I have a two search phrases that I convert to terms query:

1. With a keyword (`big`) occurrence:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "document"
          }
        }
      },
      "??? must or must_not ???" : {
        "terms": {
          "variants": ["some", "big", "search", "phrase"]
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

2. Without a keyword occurrence:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "document"
          }
        }
      },
      "??? must or must_not ???" : {
        "terms": {
          "variants": ["some", "search", "phrase"]
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

###### Now with first search I want Elasticsearch to return *only* documents `id: 1 and 3` and for second search I want to return *only* document `id: 2`.

---

Using `bool.must.terms.variants: ["some", "big", "search", "phrase"]`
Would return one document I'm looking for, but using `bool.must.terms.variants: ["some", "search", "phrase"]` would return no documents.

On the other hand if I replace `must` with `should` I'd get both documents correctly ordered by score, but **I must match only one document that follows the above rule**.

Comment: in the `keyword (big)` why document 3 not matched?

Comment: @nay you're right, documents 1 and 3 should be returned. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Should the name of the third document be "Third document" instead of "Third entry"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this may not answer your question. Since I cannot create comments yet, I'm posting this.

I dont think you can do that logic with "one" query. the logic that you describe is a two step logic.

1. Find records that matches the `variants`
2. **If no records returned**, find records that doesnt match the `variants`

You need the result of the first step to evaluate the second step.
As far as I understand, elasticsearch query is single step. the query is distributed to all shards holding the data, each shards will search independently and it will just return the result. i.e. it will not coordinate with other shards to check if other shards have matches.

Maybe you can try something with Aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

As @dna01 mentioned, you need to send two consequent requests: the first one to find documents that match the keyword, then if nothing found the second one to find documents that don't match the keyword.

You can omit extra latency added by second request by utilizing [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Just send two searches in a single request.

Request body example (let request be "some big search phrase" and keyword "big").

```json
{ }
{ "query": { "bool": {"must": [{"match": {"name": "document" }}, {"terms": {"variants": ["some", "big", "search", "phrase"]}}] } } }
{ }
{ "query": { "bool": {"must": [{"match": {"name": "document" }}, {"terms": {"variants": ["some", "big", "search", "phrase"]}}], "must_not": [{"terms": {"variants": ["big"]}}] } } }
```